# Can changing EMI through a coil change the flux through it?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, conservative-field

As the Lenz's law states, the magnitude of EMF $E=N\frac{d\phi}{dt}$, which means changing flux can change the EMF across the coil. I have the following questions:

1. Across which points is the EMF induced? And why is it that the electric field is not conservative?
2. Is the converse true? If I change the EMF E across the coil, $\phi=\int E.dt$ (And should I include the minus sign from Lenz law here?)
3. Is it necessary for the 'coil' to even be closed? I mean to say, if I change the flux over a circular region, and surround this with a loop that has a small cut in it, effectively not making it closed, the EMF will still be induced right? Also, it there any difference if the loop is conducting or non-conducting?

And how do I even change the EMF across the coil, since the field has to be non-conservative?